# Merge different dataframes having difference in column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to the `python and pandas`.Now, Here , I have the value_counts from three different dataframe columns , which I have converted into data-frame using the following,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = first_count.rename_axis('PredictedFeature').reset_index(name='counts') ,In the same way I got three dataframes ,



  df1 = 

       predictedFeature              counts
          100                          100
          200                          300
          2200                         150
            0                           11
          10                            15      
dF2 = 

   predictedFeature                counts
       100                           200
       200                           310
       2100                         150
       2200                          123
       160                            4     
        0                            100
```

df3 =

```
   predictedFeature                  counts
       100                           112
       200                           190
       3600                           89
       156                             2
       2200                          180
         0                            10
```

Now, for merging these dataframes  , I tried

```
df_final = [df1, df2, df3]
df_final_percentage = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='PredictedFeature'), df_final)
```

after doing this, it is creating the dataframe, but it is taking only the common predictedFeatures values.

So, I am getting the final dataframe like ,

```
predictedFeature    counts_x    counts_y    counts
    100                  100        200        112
    200                  300        310       190
   2200                  150       123        180
```

How can I get all the values from these three, if a predictedFeature is not present for a data-frame then there should be 0 at that place .

Output would be like ,

```
PredictedFeature        counts_x       counts_y      counts
  100                    100              200          112  
  200                    300              310          190    
  2200                   150              123          180        
  2100                    0               150           0
  160                     0                4            0 
  3600                    0                0            89    
  156                     0                0             2
```

can any one help me with this ?

One thing is that while dividing the

```
df["counts_y"] = df["counts_y"] * 100 / df["counts_x"]
df["counts_per"] = df["counts"] * 100 / df["counts_x"]
```

will the 0 in the values affects the percentage calculation ?

[image]

```
cols = ["PredictedFeature", "counts_per", "counts_y"]
    df_percentage.to_csv('data.csv', columns=cols)
```

for creating the percentage csv.

Comment: put `how='left'` in `pd.merge()` and fill nan with 0?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `outer` join with replace missing values to `0`:

```
df_final = [df1, df2, df3]
df_final_percentage = (reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, 
                                                          right, 
                                                          on='predictedFeature', 
                                                          how='outer'), df_final)
                      .fillna(0)
                      .astype(int))
print (df_final_percentage)
   predictedFeature  counts_x  counts_y  counts
0               100       100       200     112
1               200       300       310     190
2              2200       150       123     180
3              2100         0       150       0
4               160         0         4       0
5              3600         0         0      89
6               156         0         0       2
```

Another solution with `concat`:

```
dfs = [x.set_index('predictedFeature') for x in df_final]
df_final_percentage = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).fillna(0).reset_index().astype(int)
print (df_final_percentage)
   predictedFeature  counts  counts  counts
0               100     100     200     112
1               156       0       0       2
2               160       0       4       0
3               200     300     310     190
4              2100       0     150       0
5              2200     150     123     180
6              3600       0       0      89
```

EDIT1:

For filter out `0` and `10` values use:

```
df_final = [df1, df2, df3]
df_final = [x[~x['predictedFeature'].isin([0,10])] for x in df_final]
df_final_percentage = (reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, 
                                                          right, 
                                                          on='predictedFeature', 
                                                          how='outer'), df_final)
                      .fillna(0)
                      .astype(int))
print (df_final_percentage)
   predictedFeature  counts_x  counts_y  counts
0               100       100       200     112
1               200       300       310     190
2              2200       150       123     180
3              2100         0       150       0
4               160         0         4       0
5              3600         0         0      89
6               156         0         0       2
```

Comment: HI ,I have just updated the question please look at the last part .calcualting percentage part

Comment: @ganeshk - hmmm, code for percentages not working? Seems good.

Comment: and one thing is it should not have float values

Comment: No,problem will be if there is 0 in the denominator ?

Comment: @ganeshk - Hard questtion, I think mainly depends what need.

Comment: I think when it is 0 then it should return  0 should not return undefined

Comment: @ganeshk - I think tbe best should be add expected output - how looks `df["counts_y"]` and `df["counts_per"]` after percentages?

Comment: Hi added the image in the question

Comment: @ganeshk - hmmm, but image not match with sample data, can you add output from your sample data?

Comment: oh sorry .. I need to calculate the whole data

Comment: @ganeshk - no problem, only calculate by sample data

Comment: let me count all and the updated the data.. but one thing is why is it going more than 100 percent

Comment: Hey, just one thing, while merging the dataframes, I just want to add one condition that if the predictedFeature is 10 or 0 then it should not add in the final dataframe .

Comment: @ganeshk - What do you think what should be my question? Yes, you are right - `Can you add expected output from sample data`, because not understand what it means.

Comment: updated the question, In this I have updated the df1,df2 which has some more data with 0 and 10 , so that should not come in the final data frame